# How do I derive the formula for $\sum\limits_{x = 3}^{\infty} 1.536 (x^2) \left(\frac 5 8\right)^x $?

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

How would I find the summation of

$$\sum\limits_{x = 3}^{\infty} 1.536 (x^2) \left(\frac 5 8\right)^x $$

Would I have to take the 2nd derivative of $(1/1-x)$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, but it’s helpful to insert an intermediate step. Starting with

$$\frac1{1-x}=f(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n\;,$$

you get

$$\frac1{(1-x)^2}=f\,'(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0}nx^{n-1}\;,$$

and therefore

$$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}=xf\,'(x)=x\sum_{n\ge 0}nx^{n-1}=\sum_{n\ge 0}nx^n\;.$$

Now what happens if you differentiate a second time and then multiply by $x$ again?

Comment: Would I get -2x^2/(1-x)^3?

Comment: @Jesus: Your differentiation is a bit off. I get $$\frac{1-x}{(1-x)^3}$$ for the derivative of $$\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}\;.$$

Comment: Wouldn't the answer be negative? Otherwise, x is the ratio (5/8) and I would need to subtract the first 2 terms from it which would be (1.536 * 5/8) and (1.536 * 4 * (5/8)^2)?

Comment: @Jesus: No, the derivative is not negative. Yes, you’ll substitute $\frac58$ for $x$, and you’ll have to subtract the first **three** terms, the ones for $n=0$, $n=1$, and $n=2$.

Comment: WolframAlpha gives me a negative derivative  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derive+x%2F%281-x%29%5E2... when n=0, wouldn't just be 0? Are the other 2 terms correct for when n=1 and n=2?

Comment: @Jesus: But $$-\frac{x}{(x-1)^3}=\frac{x}{(1-x)^3}\;,$$ because $(1-x)^3=-(x-1)^3$. And since your $x$ is $\frac58$, which is less than $1$, I preferred to have $1-x$ rather than $x-1$. // Yes; if by *first two terms* you meant the first two **non-zero** terms, then your previous statement was correct. For me it’s the first three terms, because I wrote the summations starting at $n=0$, so there is an $n=0$ term, even though it does happen to be equal to $0$.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I didn't notice that Wolfram wrote it that way

Comment: @Jesus: You’re welcome. (It took me a moment to spot the reversed denominator, too.)

Comment: So $$\sum\limits_{x = 3}^{\infty} 1.536 (x^2) \left(\frac 5 8\right)^x $$ = (1.536) * (5/8)^2 * [(1- 5/8)/(1 - 5/8)^3] - (1.536 * 5/8) - (1.536 * 4 * (5/8)^2)?

Comment: @Jesus: The subtracted terms are okay, but the first term should be $$\frac{1.536\left(\frac58\right)\left(1+\frac58\right)}{\left(1-\frac58 \right)^3}\;,$$ if I’m not mistaken.